# C++ fix OpenCV squares.cpp sample to merge close squares

Tags: c++, algorithm, opencv, computational-geometry

I've been playing with the OpenCV squares.cpp sample to find the corner coordinates of the squares in an image.

The sample sometimes mathes each object multiple times. Now I want to "merge", calculate the average corner coordinates, for each square that seem to belong to the same object.

The resulting structure of the findSquares function is a 3-dimentional vector type structure like this:

```
[
    [[10,10],[100,10],[100,100],[10,100]], // First square
    [[100,100],[300,100],[300,100],[100,300]], // Second square
    [[8,11],[110,5],[106,109],[10,97]], // Should be meged with the first square 
    [[112,99],[296,103],[312,98],[92,300]] // Should be merged with the second square
]
```

(I'm a beginner in C++ so I'm writing the vector structure in JavaScript array notation, it's just to visialize the structure)

My idea is to:

- Find all squares matching each other (has all it's 4 points within a max distance threshold an other squares 4 points)
- Group them and calculate the average 4 points of the squares
- Save the new averaged square to a result vector

Is there a good algorithm for that? Does OpenCV have one built in? Is there a better approach to this?

Answer (score 1):

An alternative:

```
Order by `x` coordinate of first point (the point closes to the origin or something)
For each square:
   Search forwards for a matching point until the `x` coordinate is bigger than the threshold.
```

This should be about `O(nlogn+n) = O(nlogn)`, but could be `O(n^2)` if you have a lot of squares close to each other.